# Meteor.wrapAsync on an event emitter, best practice?

Tags: events, asynchronous, meteor

I am trying to wrap an async function that returns an event emitter to make it sync on the server, using `Meteor.wrapAsync`.

Here is my current implementation :

```
var wrapAsync = function(asyncFunc, context){
    return Meteor.wrapAsync(
        (data,callback)=>{
            asyncFunc(data).on('complete', function(data){
                callback(null,data)
            })
        },
        context
    )
}
```

So, my idea was :

1 - to wrap the event emitter into a classical `function(args, callback)` async function

2 - to pass it to `Meteor.wrapAsync`, that needs a function with an `(err,res)` callback as its parameter, and returns a sync function

This does not work, as the context is not correctly passed to the function. I tried with a fat arrow, but it does not work.

What is the best practice in this case ?

Comment: which part is not working? it's hard to tell from your code, but I suspect that what you need is: `(asyncFunc.bind(context))(data)`

Comment: The function sometimes does throw an error when `asyncFunc` is a method, as its context is undefined. 
I do not need to implement this function anymore as the `asyncFunc` I need to wrap actually takes a callback as its argument (it was form the badly documented Sendinblue API), but I think your solution is correct.